# Internal working of Proxy Pattern in Java?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, proxy, autowired

For following Example, in proxy pattern like Spring and Hibernate, when class A gets loaded B and C classes are not loaded until some operation like b.bgh is not done.

My question is, how does b.bgh creates an object of b when we haven't written any

b= new B();

Similarly, how does autowiring feature of spring works.?

```
  class A{
    int abc;
    B b;
    A(){
    }
    }

    class B{
    int bgh;
     C c;
    B();
    }


    class C{
    String jkl;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of brainstorming, I have reached to this answer:

Whenever the class A gets instantiated, proxy classes for B and C are made which has no data of its own.

class proxy_B{} extends B and class proxy__C extends C{}

These proxy classes satisfy the need of class A to have B and C instances.

Now when we query anything related to B and C classes,
i.e.

b.getSomething() or c.getSOmething()

At this point, actual instances of B and C are created and passed.

This is also referred to as lazy initialization.